# Android, ADB, redirecting STDOUT to a socket

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

### Environment

- Android
- C++
- ADB
- GDB

### Use-case

1. Capture a screenshot
2. do some processing
3. Send out of the device.

### Implementation ( in accordance with [this link](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/framebuffer_service.c/) )

1.Implement an ADB commandline tool
2.The tool implement a TCP server
3.1.Upon new connection, 
3.1.1. Create a socket pair
3.1.2. fork, execute "screencap" while redirecting STDOUT to the socketpair using dup2
3.1.3. process incoming data and send back to the connected peer

### Problem description

While the forked process is properly instantiated and screencap is successfully created ( as root ), the parent process ( running as shell ) doesn't receive anything on the socket pair and blocks infinitely.

- The same happen when I use pipes ( with pipe2 )
- "screencap" is verified to output what is needed on stdout.
- What am I doing wrong? 
  How can I redirect the STDOUT of one process to a socket connected to the parent process ?

### Code snap

```
int fd_screencap;
int w, h, f;
int fds[2];
pid_t pid;

if(SOCKET_ERROR == socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds))
    goto pipefail;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    goto done;
if (pid == 0) {
    int newfd = dup2(fds[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
    assert(newfd == STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
    const char* command = "screencap";
    const char *args[2] = { command, NULL };
    execvp(command, (char**)args);
    exit(1);
}

fd_screencap = fds[1];
if (recv(fd_screencap, &w, 4, MSG_WAITALL) <= 0) // <<== BLOCKS INFINITLY
    goto done;
if (recv(fd_screencap, &h, 4, MSG_WAITALL) <= 0)
    goto done;
if (recv(fd_screencap, &f, 4, MSG_WAITALL) <= 0)
    goto done;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing PF_LOCAL with PF_UNIX did the trick

Comment: It's okay to accept your own answer. It helps others find the solution easier.

Comment: 23 hours left till I will B able to do that